# C# Serialize to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class LogModel that contains a list of Logparameters.
I want to serialize this to XML.
My problem is that only the LogModel class is serialized and that the list of parameters is not added to the XML.

```
public class LogModel
{
    [XmlText]
    public String Message { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Int32 Level { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public String Owner { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Parameters")]
    public List<LogModelParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class LogModelParameter
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public DateTime ParameterDate { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Int32 Level { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Int32 Counter { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

The code for serializing is the following

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<LogModel>));
TextWriter writer  = new StreamWriter("log.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer, logModels);
```

What can be wrong?

Kind regards
Dipke

Comment: I think you have to specify `[Serializable]` attribute on your class.

Comment: Don't you need a XmlRoot element?

Comment: Always put `TextWriter` and similar classes that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements.

Comment: Did you debug and make sure logModels have LogModels with parameters inside? I couldn't reproduce, it serialized everything successfully

Comment: Why is everybody posting answers instead of comments? This turned out to be one messy thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

change your serialization method

```
 var optimizedtype = new XmlSerializer(logModels.GetType());
        using (var Writer = new StreamWriter("log.xml", false))
        {
            optimizedtype.Serialize(Writer, logModels);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change From : typeof(List) To : typeof(LogModel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LogModel logModels = new LogModel()
            {
                Message = "Hello",
                LogDate = DateTime.Now,
                Level = 123,
                Type = "Red",
                Source = "Web",
                StartDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1),
                EndDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                Owner = "Me",
                Parameters = new List<LogModelParameter>() {
                    new LogModelParameter() {
                        ParameterDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Level = 5,
                        Counter = -1,
                        Type = "Banana",
                        Text = "Hello"
                    },
                    new LogModelParameter() {
                        ParameterDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                        Level = 4,
                        Counter = 0,
                        Type = "Peach",
                        Text = "Goodbye"
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LogModel));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, logModels);

        }
    }
    public class LogModel
    {
        [XmlText]
        public String Message { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public Int32 Level { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public String Source { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
        public String Owner { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Parameters")]
        public List<LogModelParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogModelParameter
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public DateTime ParameterDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public Int32 Level { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public Int32 Counter { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public String Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public String Text { get; set; }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: He wants to serialize a list, not a single object

Comment: Read posting.  Here said the LogModel Serializes but not the parameters.

Comment: He said "LogModel class is serialized and that the list of parameters is not added to the XML" That doesn't mean he wants to serialize a single object. You cannot modify the question just to post a (non-working too!) answer

Comment: You can't have a root level as an array in XML.  So your method is impossible,

Comment: The posted code works fine. The only problem was he forgot to set the parameter values. So your suggestion is just an arbitrary change in the problem statement without identifying the problem.

Comment: As I said, the code can't work with an array at root level of xml.  Try it yourself.

Comment: I did and it works. The serializer generates a name itself

Comment: Did you add an array at root level?

Comment: What does it even mean? Anyway, the OP confirmed that it's working as is. I did so too so for me case closed.

Comment: I actually tested the code and found the issue while testing.  I know what I did is correct.

Comment: Change the type of XmlSerializer to typeof(LogModel) and pass a List<LogModel> it still works. Your code may work but it doesn't solve anything. It just changes the question in a meaningless way